# Localhost has just stopped working (using xampp)

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, xampp

I installed Xampp to use for local development of a Drupal site. Its been working fine out of the box until now.

The main Xampp localhost welcome menu loads, however my subdirectory (localhost/drupal) doesn't. It just spins in the browser for ages and nothing happens. Just a blank screen.

I've tried the edit people suggest in the hosts file but that hasn't work and I'm getting no errors so not sure what to do.

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

PS I'm running Windows 7

**edit:**

Log files:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123731968 bytes) in C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\themes\directory\node--job.tpl.php on line 41

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123731968 bytes) in C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\themes\directory\node--job.tpl.php on line 41

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.242454 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.331459 2013] [core:warn] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.820487 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.898492 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.898492 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.898492 2013] [core:notice] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:07.905492 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8432:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7588

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:08.882548 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 7588:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:09.467582 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 7588:tid 272] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Tue Nov 05 20:52:09.534585 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7588:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123731968 bytes) in C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\themes\directory\node--job.tpl.php on line 41

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123731968 bytes) in C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\themes\directory\node--job.tpl.php on line 41
```

Comment: So did Drupal EVER work? Did you undo the "edits" people suggested to ensure you're not compounding the problem?

Comment: Yes it was working for about 2-3 weeks until yesterday then it just showed a blank screen. Have undone the changes and still have the same issue.

Comment: And did you look in the log-files of xampp and php. (See [logfiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp))

Comment: Just checked (sorry didn't know this existed). Edited my post with the errors (There were a lot more but I think they're just repeated. Not sure what they mean though.

Comment: I worked out what happened. One of my PHP functions was running constantly (stupid of me) and eating up too much memory. Thanks for the help everyone!